# Prevent text overlap and keep it in center horizontal in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:maxWidth="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end" />


        <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="sometime this text is so long"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want keep the status text(tvStatus) in center horizontal (as well as center in vertical). The problem is sometime, the status text is very long, and it's overlap the textview on the left (tvUsername). Is there any way to prevent it?
I tried to add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvUsername"`, it can work but the status text doesn't keep in center horizontal

Answer (score 0):

try this it is working :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:text="fasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="sometime this text is so long"/>
```

Comment: First, I make a mistake when posting here, it should be toRightOf instead of toLeftOf. Then I tried your way, but when status text is long, it overlap tvUsername and this textview disappear

Comment: i am using it like this and it is working fine here, see the updated xml

Comment: I mean `tvStatus` text is so long, not username. Anyway, what I want to do is keep tvStatus in center horizontal and doesn't overlap tvUsername on the left

Answer (score 0):

Give `layout_width` to `wrap_content` not some specific dp(`120dp` you have used) in `tvUsername` that will solve your problem

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:text="sometime this text is so long" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="sometime this text is so long" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot from IDE]

**Linear Layout with weight**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="sometime this text is so long" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.6"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="sometime this text is so long" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase the text length? the one above for test only, this textview can be longer than it. For example: "sometime this text is so long sometime this text is so long sometime this text is so long sometime this text is so long". And it will overlap the username textview

Comment: then 1st textView will not visible coz there is *no room* for `1st textView`

Comment: in this case u might use a `LinearLayout` with *layout_weight* attribute

Comment: I tried it, but the text can't be center in it's parent with LinenearLayout and layout_weight.  Think I want to do is keep status text in center horizontal and doesn't overlap other views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvUsername"
```

and the status text is keep in center horizontal, it can't reach all. You need to redesign the layout.